# Cascade Select: Show different options when specific options is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show some options when user select a specific option. I want to hide some options from name="products", like a filter:

```
<select name="category">
   <option value="fruit">fruits</option>
   <option value="meal">meals</option>
   <option value="drink">drinks</option>
</select>

<select name="products"><!--Always visible-->
    <option default selected>select an option</option><!--when fruit is selected-->
    <option id="fruit" value="apple">apple</option>
    <option id="fruit" value="orange">orange</option><!--when meal is selected-->
    <option id="meal" value="chicken">chicken</option>
    <option id="meal" value="beef">beef</option><!--when drink is selected-->
    <option id="drink" value="vodka">vodka</option>
    <option id="drink" value="wishkey">wishkey</option>
</select>
```

I need help on how to do it with javascript or Jquery.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to change `id` in 2nd `select` to `class` since id has to be unique and you can then capture `change event` of first `select` and show only those options which match the value as below:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0aqj7wq4/2/)**

**Updated html**

```
<select name="category">
    <option value="fruit">fruits</option>
    <option value="meal">meals</option>
    <option value="drink">drinks</option>
</select>
<select name="products">
    <!--Always visible-->
    <option selected>select an option</option>
    <!--when fruit is selected-->
    <option class="fruit" value="apple">apple</option>
    <option class="fruit" value="orange">orange</option>
    <!--when meal is selected-->
    <option class="meal" value="chicken">chicken</option>
    <option class="meal" value="beef">beef</option>
    <!--when drink is selected-->
    <option class="drink" value="vodka">vodka</option>
    <option class="drink" value="wishkey">wishkey</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$("select[name='category']").on('change',function(){
   var value=$(this).val(); //get the selected value
   $('select[name="products"]').find('option:not(:first)').hide(); //hide all options except first
   $('select[name="products"]').find('option.'+value+'').show();//show only matching options
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your pront reply! its like im searching but when page load all the name="product" options are shown... how can i fix this... Thanks to much for the Answer...

Comment: so how you want at the page load? nothing to be shown?